# Why does the program show value greater than the result or garbage value?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int a =100000;
   cout<<a<<endl;
   unsigned long int pr = a*a*a;
   cout<<pr;

   return 0;
}
```

Result - 100000
18446744072179056640

whereas this code works just fine -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned long int a =100000;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    unsigned long int pr = a*a*a;
    cout<<pr;

    return 0;
}
```

Result - 100000
1000000000000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Expressions don't care about the type of the variable to which you are assigning the result***, what counts when doing an operation is the type of its operands.

In your first example you are multiplying three `int` values, so the multiplication is performed in the `int` domain and overflows. The fact that *after the result have been computed* it is assigned to an `unsigned long` variable is completely irrelevant - the result is already botched.

In the second case, instead, you are multiplying three `unsigned long` values, so the calculations are performed with the range of `unsigned long` (which I suppose on your platform is 64 bit). In this case there's no overflow, so your result is correct.

Comment: That explains a lot...thanks! :)